# DataTemplate for MVVM: where does it go?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-8

I'm working on a "Modern UI" application so the syntax is a bit new for me and I just can't seem to get my bindings to work properly.

My desire is to have a ViewModel first design so that on my apps pages I can just do things like have a `ListView` and add a `UserViewModel` as a child, and have the DataTemplate be found automatically to create a UserView and bind to the supplied UserViewModel.

I do something similar for a different app written for Win 7 desktop and it just works but for the life of me I can't figure out why it doesn't work here. I just get in my ListView "UserViewModel" as text (no UserControl created).

The only other difference here is it is the first time I'm using async functions since it pretty much is forced on you for Win 8 development, and that is the methods I get from the WCF service I'm pulling my data from.

Here's an example of my view model:

```
 public class UserViewModel
{
    private UserDTO _user { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel(UserDTO user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public UserViewModel(int userId)
    {
        SetUser(userId);
    }

    private async void SetUser(int userId)
    {
        ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
        UserDTO referencedUser = await proxy.GetUserAsync(userId);
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _user.FirstName;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _user.LastName;
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _user.email;
        }
    }
}
```

The view is supposed to be all XAML and glued together in the application resources as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TaskClient.Views.UserView" ...
    xmlns:root="using:TaskClient"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="30"
    d:DesignWidth="200">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 0, 0 ,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FirstNameLabel" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LastNameLabel" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmailLabel" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and :

```
<Application x:Class="TaskClient.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TaskClient"
xmlns:localData="using:TaskClient.Data" 
xmlns:vm="using:ViewModels"
xmlns:vw="using:TaskClient.Views">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
             -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- Application-specific resources -->

        <x:String x:Key="AppName">TaskClient</x:String>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="vm:UserViewModel">
            <vw:UserView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I've tried searching for an hour or so now through various examples (eg. http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/) and haven't been able to find an example that works in my case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a typo but you don't seem to update the "_user" field when you fetch a user via WCF service. You probably need to change this:

```
private async void SetUser(int userId)
{
    ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
    UserDTO referencedUser = await proxy.GetUserAsync(userId);
}
```

To this:

```
private async void SetUser(int userId)
{
    ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
    _user = await proxy.GetUserAsync(userId);
}
```

Also I don't see your ViewModel class implementing INotifyPropertyChange interface which is the key to WPF databinding. Once that's done and you have loaded a user, you need to notify WPF about properties being updated:

```
private async void SetUser(int userId)
{
    ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
    _user = await proxy.GetUserAsync(userId);
    NotifyOfPropertyChange();
}

private void NotifyOfPropertyChange() 
{
    NotifyChanged("FirstName"); //This would raise PropertyChanged event.
    NotifyChanged("LastName");
    NotifyChanged("Email");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just get in my ListView "UserViewModel" as text (no UserControl created)

Your `DataTemplate` needs be defined with the `DataType` property and no `x:Key` property, for the `DataTemplate` to get applied implicitly

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserViewModel}">
    <vw:UserView />
</DataTemplate>
```

A DataTemplate with a `DataType` specified but no `x:Key` is an Implicit DataTemplate, meaning it will be used implicitly anytime WPF needs to draw an object of the specified data type.

A DataTemplate with an `x:Key` property needs to actually be specified in your code by key, such as

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyKey}" ... />
```

Also, I'm not sure if the title of your question (*"DataContext for MVVM: where does it go?"*) is a typo or not since your question body doesn't appear to be asking about the `DataContext`, however I have an [beginners article on my blog explaining the DataContext](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) that you may be interested in if you're struggling to understand the `DataContext`

Comment: There is no x:Type property for Modern UI applications that is my problem. Not sure what the way around it should be.

Comment: @Mike I didn't realize that. Can you use DataTemplateSelectors? That's what I used in Silverlight before they added support for Implicit DataTemplates. Perhaps something like [this](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1705) would work?

Comment: Hi yes that would probably work. I had to workout some issues with async loading before the databinding anyways. See answer to a related question at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14189904/1462330 . Essentially I have an "initialized" task property on my viewmodels now. When you create one of them you await the initialized task so that all the WCF stuff gets loaded and the properties are assigned. I do a similar thing in the Initialized task for the Views except at the end of them I bind them to the thing they just initialized seems to work well.

Comment: Also I think you might be right with the Silverlight way of doing things. I seem to recall hearing people complain that some things went away that they were used to when using the Modern UI. I generally make 1-2 window reporting apps so most things get buried in the code behind so I don't have to do a whole lot of complicated MVVM structures very often. Looks like binding is more of a pain. Also you can't directly connect to a database anymore either from what I hear you need to use services.